# where do I get the javascript uri css referred to in http://jsfiddle.net/jrweinb/MQ6VT/

Tags: javascript, css, uri

I have found a solution on js fiddle for my "time range slider" at http://jsfiddle.net/jrweinb/MQ6VT/, but I put the code into my browser and it does not show properly (no slider) and I am sure that the reason is that i need to include the javascript/CSS URI, but I don't know where to get it, please help.

```
EXTERNAL RESOURCES
javascript/CSS URI
```

Thanks
Tom

Comment: Please define "_I put the code into my browser_".

Comment: that is a place to add external resources, it states that none currently exist.

Comment: Did you include Jquery and Jquery UI in your implementation?

Comment: DUH, No!!! That fixed it for me...

Answer (score 0):

As @Patrick Murphy mentioned above, you have to place these external resources (or copy and place on your server), in the file where your slider is going to be. Is that what you are asking for? Note that you have to call your .slider() function after all the external resources.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider();
  } );
  </script>
```